# how to fetch more than one object in parse android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
  public void getSchoolClasses(ArrayList<SchoolClass>schoolClassesIds , final CompletionHandler completionHandler){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("schoolClasses");
    query.whereContainedIn("objectId",schoolClassesIds);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null){

                for (int i =0 ; i < objects.size();i++){
                    SchoolClass schoolClass=(SchoolClass)objects.get(i);
                    schoolClass.getTeacher().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                        }
                    });
                }

            }else{
                completionHandler.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How do I know when all objects are finished being fetched and to fire the completion handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code i can understand that you have a School class and each school can have 1...many teachers. 
For that structure you should go with **pointers**. 
Pointers allows you to save one to many relation between 2 parse objects and the big advantage is that you can execute **one** api call to get all the data that you need so you will not need to call **fetch** in a loop which is a bad practice.

In order to use pointers you need to do the following:

1. Go to your School sub class and add setter and getter for teachers. The teachers will be of type List<{Teacher Sub Class object}>
2. Your query should look like the following now:

```js
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("schoolClasses");
query.whereContainedIn("objectId",schoolClassesIds);
query.include("teachers"); // this line will fetch also the teachers together with the school
```

3. In your query callback you can now access the teachers in the following way:

SchoolClass schoolClass=(SchoolClass)objects.get(i);
schoolClass.getTeachers();

4. Pointers also allows you to retrieve relation of relations by using dot notation inside the **include** function (e.g. "teachers.students" will bring all the teachers and all the students for each teacher). That is the reason why i told you to use Pointers.

You can read more about it in [here](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#using-pointers)

I also suggest you to read also on Sub Classing your parse objects. By looking at your code it looks like you are not really using it. Sub classing of parse objects allows you to keep your code more organized and also expose easy access to the parse objects.

Please read more about Subclass and how to use it in [here](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#subclasses)
It's not mandatory only a recommendation :)